# update multiple rows with current rows values mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I don't know if the title is clear but I'll try to explain it here. We have thousands of record for our database and there are a couple of datetime columns in theses tables. We have to move to int using unix_timestamp but I can't figure out a query in MySQL that would update these fields.

Let's say I have a simple table with a field like that :

```
user_table :
    id : int,
    name : string,
    date_joined : datetime;
```

To change all of these date_joined filed to a int I thought adding a int column and copying the date as a int into the new column then drop the old column and rename my new column could be a solution. I built a little php script my script will then make thousands of MySQL query which is quite long. My script would run queries like :

```
UPDATE user_table SET date_joined_int=UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_joined) where id = 1
...
```

Is this possible to do this with one MySQL query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You right, you should add new `INT` column

```
ALTER TABLE user_table ADD date_joined_int INT(11) not null;
```

Than convert your dates

```
UPDATE user_table SET date_joined_int = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_joined);
```

And finally remove `date_joined` column, and remane `date_joined_int` to `date_joined`

Answer (score 0):

You're so close. Just drop the WHERE clause to update all the rows in a single query.

```
UPDATE user_table 
    SET date_joined_int = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_joined)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the `WHERE` clause, the `UPDATE` will be applied to all rows in the table.

```
UPDATE user_table SET date_joined_int=UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_joined)
```

Comment: is this serious? hahahahaha, let me give it a shot

Comment: If you think that's fun, just try a `DELETE` with no `WHERE` clause. *evil grin*